# JSON parse array

Tags: java, json

I have been struggling with this for hours, what am I doing wrong.

I am trying to parse data from this [API](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/) using org.json library.

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(getAllCustomers());


    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        String name = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");     
    }
```

I dont even know if my code is correct, but I get an error saying that .getJSONArray() cannot find symbol, same with .getJSONObject.

What am I doing wrong here.

JSON:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "website_slug": "bitcoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Litecoin", 
        "symbol": "LTC", 
        "website_slug": "litecoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 3, 
        "name": "Namecoin", 
        "symbol": "NMC", 
        "website_slug": "namecoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 4, 
        "name": "Terracoin", 
        "symbol": "TRC", 
        "website_slug": "terracoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 5, 
        "name": "Peercoin", 
        "symbol": "PPC", 
        "website_slug": "peercoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 6, 
        "name": "Novacoin", 
        "symbol": "NVC", 
        "website_slug": "novacoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 8, 
        "name": "Feathercoin", 
        "symbol": "FTC", 
        "website_slug": "feathercoin"
    }, 
    {
        "id": 9, 
        "name": "Mincoin", 
        "symbol": "MNC", 
        "website_slug": "mincoin"
    },
```

}

**EDIT** changed from "posts" to "data". Still issues with the above methods

Comment: can you paste your json?

Comment: You give us the wrong API. In your API we do not see `posts`

Comment: Please add the entire JSON to the description

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to do,

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
```

instead of

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
```

Since, JsonObject have value key named 'data' not 'posts'

Answer (score 1):

Check 1:
If you are trying to parse the given API, then there is no array with name "posts" at all!! Try with "data" instead :-)

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data");
```

Check 2: 
You say, you still have the error even after using "data".
In that case look at what getAllCustomers() returns. Does it return a valid json string??

Check 3:
In case the getAllCustomers() returns a valid JSON, does it contain a "data" element? If yes, is that an Array?